# How to handle message body types on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, servicebus

I was writing some test code when after changing the azureRxMessage.GetBody type from int to string, I was getting the error `azure "Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'int', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'. "}`.

When looking in to this, seems bus is storing all previously sent items, so was expecting a string, but was reading an int (as was sent before). The line `var msg = azureRxMessage.GetBody<string>();` threw the error.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to handle messages? Send the body as a string (serialized to JSON), or a standard data contract?
2. What happens if a client starts spitting messages on to the bus that are not in the correct format and starts to poison the bus? How can we protect against this?

Comment: My theory (not based on much experience with the Service Bus, so I'll leave it here only as a comment) is that you should have your "application data" in a JSON string so it can easily change as your application grows. Use true properties more for metadata about the message rather than for the contents of the message: `SecurityID`, `RequestorID`, `DateSubmitted`, `ExpirationDate`, `ContainsSecureData`, etc. This is how we do our Storage Queue and Table messages/rows, seems just as applicable to Service Bus as well. That said, I'm not an expert there and certainly could be wrong! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You will likely need the ability to deploy changes to your message definitions without bleeding the queue dry first (or having new types of messages going to other queues) so using something like a dispatcher at the receiver side is a good route to take.  You can put a version number of the message type onto a [message metadata property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.properties.aspx) that could indicate the version number of the message and then use that information to know which type of object to deserialize the body to.  Or you could at first pull the content of the message as a string and use that to determine the version of the message before you deserialize it. Or, you could simply deserialize a JSON body load into a dynamic object and have your code look at it to determine how to process it.  All of these methods just mean that to survive different types of messages coming in your code will need to be able to detect which type of allowable body was passed so that it can process accordingly.

For question two Service Bus Brokered messaging does have poison message handling built in.  If you set the [MaxDeliveryCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx) on a Queue or Subscription it will deadletter a message automatically if it is attempted to be delivered more than this many times.  You can also be more proactive and as you see message bodies you don't like you can call [Deadletter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.deadletter.aspx) on it directly.